# Range input seems to ignore z-index

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a range input that is a little bit fancy )
I found it difficult to style it so i decided that the best way to do this is to create separate layers for 1) stylized `<div>` and 2) transparent `<input type="range">`

Here is the example: 
[image]

Stylized `<div` has `z-index: 2;`, `<input type="range">` has `z-index: 5; opacity: 0;`
But anyway, when i try to drag the thumb of the range, i actually just select text in the fake thumb )

Here is the [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/lucifer63/pvz2gLhc/)

How to solve this?

UPDATE: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lucifer63/pvz2gLhc/7/) is the example in which the problem is solved.

Comment: Have you tried visibility hidden?

Comment: Nop, but you see, problem is solved already)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index), [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) only applies to positioned elements.

Just set the `<input>`'s `position` to `relative`:

```
input {
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}
```

```js
$.each($('input'), function() {
  var thumb = $(this).next(),
    target = thumb.find('span'),
    change = function() {
      target.html(this.value);
      thumb.css('left', 'calc(' + this.value + '% - 26px*' + (this.value / 100));
    };

  $(this).on('input change', function() {
    thumb.css("background-color", "");
    change(), $(this).off('input change', arguments.callee).on('input change', change);
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

div.thumb {
  background-color: rgba(0, 102, 153, 0.75);
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 26px;
  z-index: 2;
}

div.range {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75%;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #cc3300;
  /* Old browsers */
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #cc3300 0%, #009900 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #cc3300), color-stop(100%, #009900));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #cc3300 0%, #009900 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #cc3300 0%, #009900 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #cc3300 0%, #009900 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #cc3300 0%, #009900 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cc3300', endColorstr='#009900', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-8 */
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.45px 0;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 26px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 26px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 26px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range">
  <input type="range">
  <div class="thumb" style="left: calc(50% - 13px); background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);"><span>?</span>%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, i got it a second ago( I just removed `float: left` and added `position: absolute`, and now everything's alright. Sorry for such a stupid question (